# Having trouble with implementing the native react map into my expo native react application

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-maps

I'm building a dog adoption app and I have it setup where there's three major screens.(home page, search page, and the profile page. The documentation for using Map View is based on if you're building it on the App.js file but I want to have it on another screen.

this is my App.js file so far:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Text, Image, View, Button, TouchableOpacity, Alert, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { ProfileScreen } from './Components/Profile.js';
import { HomeScreen } from './Components/Home.js';
import { SearchScreen } from './Components/Search.js';
import { MapView, Permissions } from 'react-native-maps';





export default function App({ navigation }) {
  return (
      <NavigationContainer> 
        <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        headerStyle: {backgroundColor: 'white', }, headerTitleStyle: {fontSize: 30}, headerTransparent: true, }}>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={({navigation}) => ({title:'Rescue Me',
          headerRight: () => (
            <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5}
            onPress={() => Alert.alert('Left button pressed')}>
              <Image
                source={require('./assets/icon-ios.png')}
                style={{width:50, height: 50}}
              />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          ), 
          headerRightContainerStyle: {paddingRight: 10},
          headerLeftContainerStyle: {paddingRight: 10}})}
          />

          <Tab.Screen name="Search" component={SearchScreen} options={{title:'Search', 
          headerRightContainerStyle: {paddingRight: 10},
          headerLeftContainerStyle: {paddingRight: 10}}}
          />

          <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} options={{title:'Profile', 
          headerRightContainerStyle: {paddingRight: 10},
          headerLeftContainerStyle: {paddingRight: 10}}}
          />

        </Tab.Navigator>
        
      </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const HeaderStyle = StyleSheet.create({

});

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  
});
```

so far all three screens are in different js files under my Components folder and my Search file that I want my map in is this so far:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Text, Image, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import React from 'react';
import { MapView, Permissions } from 'react-native-maps';



export function SearchScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <MapView style={styles.map} />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  map: {
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
    height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
  },
});
```

but my error is saying
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `SearchScreen`.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when component is not correctly import / export.

You may try change export your SearchScreen Component by **default**.

```
export default function SearchScreen() {
```

and change your import statement in `App.js`

```
import SearchScreen from './Components/Search.js'
```

Comment: I tried that but, it still gave the same error.

Comment: The error still say it occurs in `SearchScreen`? Since you have 3 pages which use the similar import format.